# Mac OS. Can't zip or copy a folder?

Tags: macos, file-transfer

It is a folder with xcode project. Previously it worked normally.

Now on both duplicating and zipping it shows an error. It is in other language but sounds something like this "Error on zipping file".

But copying to desktop works for this folder.

**UPDATED**

On copying it shows something like this:

"Can't finish the operation, because you haven't permissions to access to some objects.

Google translates as:

"Unable to complete the operation because you do not have access rights to some of the objects."

Comment: Could you use Google Translate to put the actual error message in?

Comment: I translated a message for copying error with google translate. Is it enough for you?

Comment: There's your answer, you don't have permissions as a user to access all the files within the directory.  You could just jump into terminal, and then issue sudo chown -R <your username> /path/to/directory